# Is there a kind of Wizard/Guide embeddable for SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, plugins, wizard

#### The Short Form

*Is there some sort of iterative wizard tool that can be embedded into a SharePoint site?*

#### Background That Drives the Question

Our environment is a geographically distributed collection of technicians, who serve customers as they arrive at a specific location. Customers usually bring one or more issues. Many of these issues (computer related) are common, because they are often a result of some globally-deployed change by a vendor, etc.

I had this crazy idea, inspired by a high-school "what animal am I thinking of" program: building an iteratively-smarter tool that allows techs to query the tool for an issue, and add to the data if they encounter something new. And then the next tech to come along in a few minutes, with the same issue, sees the new solution. It goes from simple-to-complex as far as troubleshooting

We currently run a Slack channel, which is... k-i-n-d-a used for some of that functionality, but Slack channels get old and stale and searching depends on "asking the exact right kind of question". We also have a KB system, but again, that depends on knowing which question to ask.

I have in the past set up this same kind of "Choose Your Own Adventure" style thing just using linked pages, but as you might imagine that becomes extremely onerous in a dynamic environment.

But then it occurred to me that SharePoint might already have such a tool as a plug-in or something, and we have an active SharePoint site we use already as a reference. But my Google-Fu must really suck because all I can find are wizards and tools for *installing* SharePoint.

Thank you kindly,

Edward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using a series of linked pages. Each page was a bit of text, and a question that had multiple answers. Each answer was a link that drove you to another page that helped you better tune your questions. Eventually, you end up at a page that claims "this is the most likely candidate." Each page also has an email link back to me whose link text is "Click here if you are encountering an option or issue for which there is no viable choice above."

It was a terrible solution, and non-dynamic, but at least it was somewhat fast and a no-brainer to design.